# How to check whether site is wordpress or not

Tags: python, wordpress

Please see this function and update it. I just need to whether site is wordpress or not using this function please help me.

```
def getWordpress(): # yes/no 
    print("—Extracting Wordpress") 
    content = '' 
    for meta in soup.findAll("meta"): 
        metaname = meta.get('name', '').lower() 
        print ('>>>',metaname) 
        if metaname == 'generator': 
            print ("True) 
            if "WordPress" in meta.get('content'): 
                print ('>>>><<>><<<><') 
                return 'Yes' 
            else:
                print('KL:L":"L"11')
                return 'No' 
        else:
             return 'No'
```

Comment: Instead of screenshot if you have put up the function here, It could have a better.

Comment: sometimes the meta-tag generator is disable then how you will track. It will be better to hit on specific url of wordpress like https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php OR xmlrpc.php. This url always return some values.